# Update specific text in file from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to update specific entries in a document from a user prompt in a shell script. The user should be promoted to enter their domain name and then the script should update the 'yourdomain.com' section on 3 different lines. The name of the text file is .env

```
IMAGE_REPO=tacticalrmm/
VERSION=latest
TRMM_USER=username
TRMM_PASS=password

APP_HOST=rmm.yourdomain.com
API_HOST=api.yourdomain.com
MESH_HOST=mesh.yourdomain.com
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: The answer you accepted here provides you with some code so you could ask a new question about how to do what you want robustly without that question getting closed for lack of an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is very easy, you can use `sed` to update specific entries in the .env file from a shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter your domain name: " domain

sed -i "s/yourdomain.com/$domain/g" .env

echo "Updated values:"
cat .env
```

***I've helped you this time, but remember that no one here is writing code for anyone, we're here to solve your problems in your code and help you!***

Comment: That worked thank you so much freeman! And dually noted.

Comment: If I wanted to append something to the domain name like dash.yourdomain.com could I do that with the following?   sed -i "s/yourdomain.com/dash$domain/g" .env

Comment: @JordanMatthewFarmer fyi "dually noted" means you noted it twice, ITYM "duly noted".

Comment: That would fail if `fooyourdomain.com` or `yourdomainxcom.net` (the `.` is a metachar) existed in the input (e.g. `APP_HOST=rmm.fooyourdomain.com`), or some other field contained `yourdomain.com` (e.g. `TRMM_PASS=yourdomainscommercial`), or the user entered a `&` or `/` or `\1` or various other characters at the prompt. Don't do this if you need a robust solution. It's usually trivial to match the text you expect but much harder to not match text you don't expect. Btw, the `g` at the end isn't useful or desirable as you only want to do this replacement once per line.